# access backend storage from the view in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a Dashboard for a personal project,
**I want the storage of the Dashboard to be completely separate from the front end**,
I create a new disk in the filesystem.php and this is the details:

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'backend' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/backend'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

[image: this is my folder structure]

after that, I try to store some avatars and it works perfectly,
my problem is when I want to access the files from the view side,

**Note that I try the visibility on both public and private**
,also
**I want to store sensitive files inside it**
so I try:

```
url('/storage/avatars/filename.png'),

storage_path('backend/avatars/filename.png'),

storage::disk('backend')->get('avatars/filename.png'),
```

but nothing.

Comment: ```php artisan storage:link```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your question exactly? I assume you are trying to display images on a webpage, but they are not showing up?

This has to do with the visibility of your files. Only files in the `storage/app/public` directory are available for display. So images that should be visible using a URL, should be stored in that directory.

The best practice here is to upload the image to the [Public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk). Make sure to create the symoblic link using `php artisan storage:link`.

For any other non-public file, you can set-up a Controller to return a [download response](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files)

Another option is to display content right away in the browser, like a PDF. In that case, you should set the correct `Content-Type` while returning the response, with the contents of the PDF.

If this did not answer your question, please let me know.

Comment: **Only files in the storage/app/public directory are available for display** , this answers my question, thank you.